# How to highlight digit groups of 3 in numerals?

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I find it very useful to visually distinguish every 3 digit group of numbers in source code so that I can read it. For example something if I see 1**000**000 it is fairly easy to see that this is 1M rather than 10M or 100k. Basically I want to made digits 4-6, 10-12... look different from the others.

In vim I could do this via a custom syntax rule.

```
match SpellRare /\d\{1,3}\ze\%(\%(\d\{3}\)\{2}\)*\d\{3}\>/
```

This relies on zero-length lookaheads to work. Emacs highlighting doesn't appear to have these so the best I could do was multiple `highlight-regexp` calls.

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)\\([0-9]\\{3\\}\\|\\)\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{9\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{15\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{21\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{27\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{33\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)
    (highlight-regexp "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)[0-9]\\{39\\}\\>" font-lock-warning-face 1)))
```

This mostly works for the number lengths I have defined (although it doesn't always update correctly when editing the number). Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: You could use an "anchored" font-lock rule to match the number and highlight rules to highlight the groups of three characters you want to match. It might require some elisp to do this, but it wouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate the `\ze` construct using repeated matching. See also `(info "(elisp) Search-based Fontification")`.

```
(defun my-matcher (limit)
  (when (re-search-forward
         "\\([0-9]\\{1,3\\}\\)\\(?:[0-9]\\{6\\}\\)*\\(?:[0-9]\\{3\\}\\)\\_>" limit t)
    (goto-char (match-beginning 1))
    (re-search-forward "[0-9]+" (match-end 1))))

(font-lock-add-keywords nil '((my-matcher 0 font-lock-warning-face)))
```